# When is this polynomial equal to a square?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

When is $f(k):=8k^2+8k+1$ a square for $k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$?

How do I begin on this? I see $f(k)$ is a square for $k=0,2$, but I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Set your polynomial equal to $w^2,$ with $w$ a new variable. Add $1$ to both sides. What do you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$y^2=8k^2+8k+1=2(2k+1)^2-1=2x^2-1$, $y^2-2x^2=-1$ is (more-or-less) a [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), concerning which there is a large and readily-available literature. One solution is $x=y=1$. If you let $(1+\sqrt2)^n=y_n+x_n\sqrt2$ for $n$ odd, then you'll have $y_n^2-2x_n^2=-1$, and in fact all solutions arise this way.

Answer (score 5):

This is a well-known integer sequence $0, 2, 14, 84, 492, 2870, 16730,\ldots$ with many interesting characterizations, see the OEIS entry [A053141](https://oeis.org/A053141).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found among Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$, where $c$ is perfectly square.
$$8k^2+8k+1=2(2k+1)^2−1=a^2,\quad    (a^2+1)/2=(2k+1)^2$$  The left side of this equation describes the "$c=b+1$" sequence of Pythagorean triples. 
So, your equation is square when $k =(\sqrt{c}- 1)/2$   or, when $k=(z-1)/2$.

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
    a    &   7    &  41    &  239     &  1393     &  8119     &   47321    &    275807   &      1607321 \\
    b  &  24   &  840   & 28560    & 970224  & 32959080 &  1119638520  & 38034750624   & 1291740398520\\
    c  &   25   &  841  &  28561  &   970225 &  32959081  & 1119638521  & 38034750625  & 1291740398521\\
    x,y  & 3,4  &  20,21 & 119,120  & 696,697 & 4059,4060&  23660,23661  &37903,137904  & 803760,803761
\end{array}$$

The fascinating thing about these triples is the $(x,y,z)$ sequence from which they derive. In this sequence, $y=x+1$, and $x+y=a$, and $z^2=c=x^2+y^2$.  What's more, $z=m^2+n^2$.

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
    x   &     3  &    21    &   119    &     697    &  4059      &     23661   &  137903    &   803761\\
    y    &    4  &    20     &  120      &   696    &  4060       &    23660  &   137904 &      803760\\
    z   &     5    &  29     &  169     &    985    &  5741     &      33461   &  195025   &   1136689\\
    m,n  &   1,2  &   2,5  &   12,29     &  29,70   & 70,169   &     169,408    & 408,985  &  985,2378
\end{array}$$